# How to change color in TextButton.icon

Tags: flutter, iconbutton

I want to have an icon with text, so I used `TextButton.icon` but I can not change the color of the text or icon!
Please suggest if anyone has a solution
this is my code:

```
SizedBox(height: 8,),
        TextButton.icon(
          icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
          label: Text('delete'),

          onPressed: (){},
        ),
```

Comment: ``icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red)`` and ``label: Text('delete', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red))``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the TextButton.stylefrom on the style of the TextButton. In this method, you can use primary to set the colors of both the icon and label. If you want to set another color for the icon, you can set the icon color in Icon.

```
TextButton.icon(
   onPressed:(){},
   style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
   ),
   icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit, color: Colors.red),
   label: Text("label"),
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Emmanuel Ashitey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71015276/19444062)'s answer, the "primary" method has been deprecated as of v3.1.0 (per VSCode tooltips) and should be replaced with "foregroundColor":

```
TextButton.icon(
    onPressed: () {},
    icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
    label: const Text('Delete'),
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
    ),
),
```

Obviously `Theme.of(context).errorColor` can be replaced with `Colors.red` for this scenario.

Comment: Great work updating the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.
Refer `TextButton` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html)

```
TextButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.delete,
    color: Colors.red,//for icon color
  ),
  label: Text(
    'Delete',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,//for text color
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]